# Shadow doesn't overflow when using React Native FlatList. It's works without FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, shadow, flatlist

Image
https://ibb.co/vJM305f

I am using FlatList to display a horizontal list. Each item has a showdow, which overflows over other items. It works without FlatList. But unfortunality not with FlatList.

I have attached a image above. Its shows a shadow line which is the issue.
Instead is should look like the below image.
https://ibb.co/6NWtcTK

```
 <FlatList
    data={[1, 1, 1]}
    horizontal
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    contentContainerStyle={{padding: RFPercentage(2)}}
    renderItem={() => {
      return (
        <Card style={[infoCardStyle, styles.infoCard]}>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
              <View style={{flex: 0.1}}>
                <Icon
                  name={'lightbulb-on-outline'}
                  size={RFValue(20)}
                  color="#fff"
                />
              </View>
              <View style={{flex: 0.9}}>
                <Title style={styles.didYouKnow}>Did you know?</Title>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.description}>
              <View style={{flex: 0.1}} />
              <View style={{flex: 0.9}}>
                <Text style={styles.descriptionText}>
                  Your can watch your game clip play by{'\n'}play in REPS
                  application
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.trailingText}>
            <Text style={styles.getAppNow}>Get the app now...</Text>
          </View>
        </Card>
      );
    }}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
```